# Why do we need parentheses or new variable when calculating sum of inverted Series of booleans?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given some data:

```
>> s = pd.Series([True, False, True, False, True])
```

---

```
>> ~s.values == (~s).values
array([True,  True, True,  True, True])
```

But

```
>> ~s.values.sum()
-4 
>> (~s).values.sum()
2
```

And

```
>> x = ~s.values
>> x.sum() == (~s).values.sum()
True
```

Why do we need to use parentheses `(~s).values` or store `~s.values` in a new variable in order for `~Series.sum()` to give us the correct number of `False` values in `s`?

---

This is because of precedence, as stated by @juanpa.arrivillaga and @cwallenpoole. Indeed:

```
>> ~3 is -4
True
```

Comment: Seriously, I know there's a lot of reasons to downvote questions on the main feed but the few interesting and well-considered questions are attracting downvotes tonight that I don't think they deserve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of attribute access is higher than the precedence of the `~` operator. So it is summed before it is negated.

A lot of the numpy/pandas objects override the bitwise operators for vectorized computations. Unfortunately, that will cause them to behave unexpectedly.

In other words, it is getting evaluated as:

```
~((s.values).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with evaluation order (or [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)). `~` produces the inversion of the expression to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Without parentheses first sum() is called with the original values. The result of sum() is then inverted.  With (~values).sum the values are inverted first and then sum() is caled with the inverted list.